# Python logging stops working if getLogger is called more than once for the same logger

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I apologize if this was already answered, but it is kind of hard to search for this particular behaviour.

Using the following snippet of code as an example:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml

myconfig = '''version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  standard_output:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [standard_output]
'''

def get_logger(name):
  logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.safe_load(myconfig))
  mylogger = logging.getLogger(name)
  return mylogger

l = get_logger(__name__)
for i in range(0, 10):
  l.error("Test")

def tryme(msg):
  l = get_logger(__name__)
  l.error(msg)

tryme("one")
tryme("two")
```

The loop seems to work just fine and I can see the `Test` message printed 10 times. But the other two log messages that should be printed via tryme() don't show up. If I change the logger name so something else it works fine as long as I do call it more than once. Why?

I was expecting a new instance of the logger object fully usable.

Comment: If you move the `dictConfig()` call out of the function, it works.  So somehow it's a consequence of calling `dictConfig` more than once.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that during my troubleshooting session but it helps a lot, thanks! I would still like to understand exactly what causes that behaviour though.